# Why Bundler.require is not working the way it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gem-bundler

I have an application where I segregated all my gem based on groups

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

...
...
...


group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'web-app-theme', '>= 0.6.2'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'mailcatcher'
  gem "pry"
  gem 'annotate'
  gem "unicorn"
  gem "capistrano"
end
```

The important Thing over here is **ruby-debug19** 
now in my **config/application.rb**
I have defined

```
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
```

Still when I start my server

> rails server --debugger

it give me this below error

> `require': no such file to load -- ruby-debug (LoadError)

I have remove the ruby-debug19 from development group and put it in default it the server works

I compared the both the Gemfile.lock in either case

> cat Gemfile.lock > intial_lock (When ruby-debug19 is in development group)

ran

> bundle list 
>   cat Gemfile.lock > final_lock (When ruby-debug19 is in default group)

also did a

> diff initial_lock final_lock

No difference indicating the file are same

I also tried with

> Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)

Still no success

Can anyone let me know why Bundler.require is not working the way it should have

Comment: Strange did you ever run bundle install with --without options

Comment: @Viren, Yes Does that make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have not fall into the .bundle directory trap in your application directory It happen when you any time run anytime bundle install with --without options

Straight from bundle Gemfile [manual](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html)

> After running bundle install --without test, bundler will remember
>   that you excluded the test group in the last installation. The next
>   time you run bundle install, without any --without option, bundler
>   will recall it.

just remove .bundle/config directory from your application directory please first check the content first before removing it

Hope this help